# What is the definition of non-degenerate $C^*$-subalgebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, $A^\prime$ is a non-degenerate $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$. What is the definition of non-degenerate $C^*$-subalgebra? Is it defined as following :

There exists an inclusion $l:A^\prime \to M(A)$ such that $l(A^\prime)(A)$ is dense in $A$?

Comment: Probably, $A'$ has an approximate unit which is also an approximate unit for $A$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251626/induced-map-on-state-spaces?r=SearchResults, is this the precise definition?

Comment: @Epsilon does it mean the inclusion map from $A^\prime$ to $A$ is non-degenerate?